# unfortunately <OpenGL Sample app> has stopped

Tags: android, opengl

I am trying run a sample OpenGL30 app
Platform: ubuntu 12.04. adreno-sdk-linux. When I run it I am getting the error:"Unfortunately  has stopped"
My output is given below:
    java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.put(HeapByteBuffer.java:200)
    at com.android.ddmlib.JdwpPacket.movePacket(JdwpPacket.java:235)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Debugger.sendAndConsume(Debugger.java:347)
    at com.android.ddmlib.Client.forwardPacketToDebugger(Client.java:665)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.processClientActivity(MonitorThread.java:344)
    at com.android.ddmlib.MonitorThread.run(MonitorThread.java:263)

Can anyone help?

Comment: I would say the exception says it all. You're trying to use more heap memory than the system has available for you. You most likely have memory leaks in your app...

Comment: Thanks peedee.What is the solution?

Comment: As @peedee said: You are either allocating more memory than available or you have a memory leak. Case 1: Cut down your memory allocations, Case 2: Find the place in your code where you allocate memory, but don't release it.